# Syntax highlighting: <!-​- language: lang-none --> does not seem to work for block quote

Tags: bug, code-formatting, syntax-highlighting, markdown-rendering

After using `<!-- language-all: lang-sql -->`, this is formatted as SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM foo LIMT 12345;
```

Next, a block quote (to keep line breaks!), but language syntax is not desired.
So I use `<!-- language: lang-none -->`:

> ```sql
> Keep line breaks, but no syntax highlighting, please: SELECT * FROM foo LIMT 12345;
>                                               --------^ here!
> ```

**The above does not seem to work, currently.**
It does not get through to code in the block quote.
However, `<!-- language-all: lang-none -->` works:

> ```
> Keep line breaks, but no syntax highlighting, please: SELECT * FROM foo LIMT 12345;
>                                               --------^ here!
> ```

But I really did not want to use `<!-- language-all: lang-none -->`. I want SQL format again:

```
SELECT * FROM foo LIMT 12345;
```

Now I have to use `<!-- language-all: lang-sql -->` again:

```sql
SELECT * FROM foo LIMT 12345;
```

Related:
[What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)

Answer (score 19):

The highlighting hint only works when it's placed immediately before the code block. When the code block is inside a list or blockquote, the hint *also* needs to be inside that list or blockquote. However, it looks like our system doesn't properly parse the hint if it's the very first thing in the blockquote.

So this will parse out the hint and incorrectly leave an empty paragraph instead of changing the syntax highlighting:

```sql
> <!-- language: lang-none -->

>     Keep line breaks, but no syntax highlighting, please: SELECT * FROM foo LIMT 12345;
```

But this (kind of a workaround) will correctly apply the highlighting hint inside the blockquote:

```sql
>  

> <!-- language: lang-none -->

>     Keep line breaks, but no syntax highlighting, please: SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 12345;
```

Which renders as:

> ```
> Keep line breaks, but no syntax highlighting, please: SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 12345;
> ```

No syntax highlighting!

Comment: Excellent, insightful answer. The only reason I am not *accepting* it is that I am hoping for a fix instead of a workaround.

Comment: Still no fix :( Though I am so pleased you found a work around!

Answer (score 8):

For completeness: You *can* use a **`<pre>`** block to work around the issue in this particular case.
Like:

```
<pre>
Keep line breaks, but no syntax highlighting, please: SELECT * FROM foo LIMT 12345;
                                              --------^ here!
</pre>
```

Displayed as:

```
Keep line breaks, but no syntax highlighting, please: SELECT * FROM foo LIMT 12345;
                                              --------^ here!
```

Without highlighted syntax like in:

```
SELECT * FROM foo LIMIT 12345;
```

But that only works for `lang-none`, since a `<pre>` block happens to do the same. Not for other syntax variants.